# Objective c - How save text style with SQLite?

Tags: ios, sqlite, tableview

I'm creating a note management app. To save the various notes I am using SQLite. The problem is that if I modify a note, for example, change the font or turn it into bold or italic and then save it, when re-extracting the note, it has lost (of course) all the attributes and is written in a normal way. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please show the structure of your database, i.e. some lines of `Create table ...` and some sample content, i.e. some lines of `insert into ...`. Use `.dump`for convenience.

Comment: My is a simple SQLite table with 4 fields type string..

Comment: Great so it won't take you long to type those structure and content lines. Or use `.dump` from SQlite commandline tool.

Comment: @Yunnosch sqlite> .dump test
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE test(id integer primary key, name text, version text, company text);
COMMIT;
sqlite>

Comment: If you want help getting your code working, you need to [edit] your question with your relevant code (as text, not a picture).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store the attributed string, not just the string. Then use NSKeyedArchiver to convert it to raw data. There are a couple of ways to go after that but you can try converting to base64 and then storing it in a blob. Try this to convert the data. In my case "report" is an NSTextView;

```
  NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
  NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
  [archiver encodeObject:report.textStorage forKey:@"attrs"];
  [archiver finishEncoding];

  NSString *encodedString = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
```

The resulting string, encodedString can be inserted into SQLite.

To get it back out reverse the process;

```
  NSString *reportCoded = [aReportRecord valueForKey:@"reportContents"];

  NSData *decodedData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:reportCoded options:NSDataBase64DecodingIgnoreUnknownCharacters];

  NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:decodedData];

  NSAttributedString* newString = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey :@"attrs"];

  [[self.report textStorage] appendAttributedString:newString];
```